# FP Growth (Frequent Pattern Mining) Giving Error with Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, fpgrowth

I have been trying to use the Frequent Pattern Mining Algorithm as in the example with PySpark. The code used to work.

```
from pyspark.ml.fpm import FPGrowth

df = spark.createDataFrame([(0, [1, 2, 5]),(1, [1, 2, 3, 5]),(2, [1, 2])], ["id", "items"])

fpGrowth = FPGrowth(itemsCol="items", minSupport=0.5, minConfidence=0.6)
model = fpGrowth.fit(df)

model.freqItemsets.show()
```

Source:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-frequent-pattern-mining.html

I am getting the error with .fit:

```
An error occurred while calling o448.fit.: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:449)
at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:103)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:262)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2292)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2066)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2092)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth.genFreqItems(FPGrowth.scala:249)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth.run(FPGrowth.scala:216)
at org.apache.spark.ml.fpm.FPGrowth.genericFit(FPGrowth.scala:167)
at org.apache.spark.ml.fpm.FPGrowth.fit(FPGrowth.scala:157)
at org.apache.spark.ml.fpm.FPGrowth.fit(FPGrowth.scala:127)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

I use:

- Spark 2.3.0
- Java 9

How do I fix this?
​

Comment: Works fine for me in 2 2.1 and 2.3.0. From the looks of it, it might be some configuration / version mismatch problem.

Comment: My version is spark 2.3.0, java 9

Comment: That explains it. Java 9 is not supported in Spark. You have to downgrade to Java 8.

Comment: That worked. Thanks